# Counting in a Prolog List

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to make a prolog function (I know it's not a function but I can't recall it's name) that given a list and a number N returns a list with the elements that repeat at least N times.

xpto(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], Out, 3)
should return Out = ['a']

xpto(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], Out, 2)
should return Out = ['a', 'b']

etc.

I currently have:

```
xpto([], _, _).

xpto([H | L], O, Num) :-
    count(H, [H | L], N),
    N = Num,
    xpto(L, [H | O], Num).

xpto([H | L], O, Num) :-
    count(H, [H | L], N),
    N \= Num,
    xpto(L, O, Num).
```

where in count(A, L, N) N is the number of times A repeats in L, however it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure my algorithm works on paper.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

If your Prolog system supports [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), you could use the following implementation of
`xpto/3`. The implementation preserves [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity)!

Let's implement `xpto/3` based on 
[`list_counts/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30027124/4609915), the meta-predicates
[`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211229/4609915) and 
[`maplist/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3), and on `(#=<)/3`. `(#=<)/3` is a reified version of the constraint `(#=</2)`.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

xpto(Xs,Ys,N) :-
   list_counts(Xs,Css0),
   tfilter(N+\ (_-V)^(N #=< V),Css0,Css1),
   maplist(\ (K-_)^K^true,Css1,Ys).
```

Let's run the queries you gave in your questions:

```
?- xpto([a,a,a,b,b,c],Out,3).
Out = [a].                        % succeeds deterministically

?- xpto([a,a,a,b,b,c],Out,2).
Out = [a,b].                      % succeeds deterministically
```

As the code used in this implementation is **monotone**, we can ask quite general queries and still get **logically sound answers**:

```
?- xpto([a,a,a,b,b,c],Out,N).
Out = [],      N in 4..sup ;
Out = [a],     N = 3       ;
Out = [a,b],   N = 2       ;
Out = [a,b,c], N in inf..1 .
```

Now what do the answers look like if the first argument contains variables?

```
?- Xs = [_,_],xpto(Xs,Out,N).
Xs = [_A,_A], Out = [],       N in 3..sup             ;
Xs = [_A,_A], Out = [_A],     N in inf..2             ;
Xs = [_A,_B], Out = [],       N in 2..sup, dif(_A,_B) ;
Xs = [_A,_B], Out = [_A, _B], N in inf..1, dif(_A,_B) .
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider instead:

```
xpto(L, O, Num) :-
    % check Num is indeed a valid number
    number(Num), Num >= 0,
    % build element occurrence list EO
    elem_occ(L, EO),
    % extract all occurrences which occur at least C times
    findall(E, (member(E-Num0, EO), Num0 >= Num), O).

% computes occurrences O of elements E in a list as E-O
elem_occ([], []).
elem_occ([E|Es], [E-O|EOs]) :-
    filter([E|Es], E, ML, NL),
    length(ML, O),
    elem_occ(NL, EOs).

% filters occurrences of E from the input list and returns the remainder
filter([], _, [], []).
filter([E|Es], E, [E|Ms], Ns) :-
    !, filter(Es, E, Ms, Ns).
filter([E|Es], E0, Ms, [E|Ns]) :-
    filter(Es, E0, Ms, Ns).
```

Verifying with your examples:

```
?- xpto(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], Out, 3).
Out = [a].

?- xpto(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], Out, 2).
Out = [a, b].
```

This solution is likely to work on most variants of Prolog (SWI, GNU, SICStus, YAP).